# Interpret division by zero as nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to divide one array by another, say

```
a = np.array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2.], [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]])
b = np.array([[20., 16., 0., 10., nan], [5., 4., nan, 2., 0.]])

np.divide(a,b)
```

will result in

```
array([[ 0.1  ,  0.125,    inf,  0.2  ,    nan],
       [ 0.4  ,  0.5  ,    nan,  1.   ,    inf]])
```

and gives me the error RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide, which doesn't come as a big surprise.

I tried

```
try:
    np.divide(a,b)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    value = float('nan')
```

which didn't work. Also an if-loop wasn't the solution:

```
if b != 0:
    value = a / b
else:
    value = float('nan')
```

gives me the error 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'. But using

```
if np.any(b != 0):
```

as a first line instead, yields

```
array([[ 10. ,   8. ,   0. ,   5. ,   nan],
       [  2.5,   2. ,   nan,   1. ,   0. ]])
```

Same goes for

```
 if np.all(b != 0):
```

I do understand that this must be due to the fact that np.any just returns a boolean True or False. Is there no other option as to replace inf-values that come up with

```
np.divide(a,b)
```

and accept the RuntimeWarning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.isinf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) to replace `inf` and `-inf` values with `np.nan`:

```
c = np.divide(a,b)
c[np.isinf(c)] = np.nan

print(c)

[[ 0.1    0.125    nan  0.2      nan]
 [ 0.4    0.5      nan  1.       nan]]
```